# Alternatives to Faraday's Cage?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Microwave ovens contain (or are made up of) a Faraday's cage which are used to "keep" the microwave radiation from leaking to the outside. Are there any alternatives for using a Faraday's Cage?  Not much as alternatives, but like similar devices.

Comment: Forgive me, but what's wrong with Faraday's cage. I mean, have you an alternative in mind? I can't personally think of anything that wouldn't be much the same as the cage.

Comment: You could use dielectric mirrors, which in case of microwave wavelengths would be extremely bulky. :-)

Comment: @count_to_10 Nothing is really wrong with the cage, I just exploring if there are any alternatives to the cage.